# What is the difference between the natures of finding average value using secant slope and integral?

Tags: definite-integrals, average

To my knowledge, there are two ways of finding average (what average I am not too sure, forgot what my teacher said. But I think it has something to do with the mean value theorem)

Say you have a velocity-versus-time graph:

[image]

The 1st way of finding the average (acceleration?) is by using the slope of secant line: $$m_\text{secant}=\frac{v(b)-v(a)}{b-a}$$

Well, since (I just found out) the secant method is for finding average **acceleration**, when using the integral method, we need to first take the derivative of v(t), whose graph is shown, to get a(t). $$a_\text{avg}=\frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b a(t) \, dt$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we assume that
$$
v'(t)=a(t),\quad t\in [a,b],
$$ then there is **no difference**, since
$$
\int_{a}^{b} a(t) dt=\int_{a}^{b} v'(t) dt=v(b)-v(a),
$$ giving
$$
a_{avg}=\frac{1}{b-a} \int_{a}^{b} a(t) dt=\frac{v(b)-v(a)}{b-a}=m_{secant}.
$$

Comment: Yeah, should have attempted it myself. But too lazy to try.